# Does fusioncharts work with a remote swf?

Tags: flash, fusioncharts

see:

```
var mychart = new FusionCharts("http://localhost/xx.swf")
```

it is from my local computer
it works fine!!

but another

```
var mychart = new FusionCharts("http://192.168.1.44/xx.swf")
```

This is from another pc.
it doesnot work.

why ?

ths.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it should work. However, if you are running the HTML from local file system and you are trying to access a remote URL many browsers like Chorme will prevent this access.

You need to check the browser's Network debugging tool to see if the SWF is being loaded correctly.

Again, as the SWF is present in a different domain, the SWF will not allow cross-domain JavaScript to SWF (vice versa) scripting. It can be handled in 2 steps:

1. While loading the SWF from another domain, you need to keep a cross-domain policy file in that server while will declare which domain to allow access.
2. If you have the Flash source-code of the chart, you need to add allow all domains in the action-script code (AS2) of the charts and recompile them and re-use.

`System.security.allowDomain ("*");`

References:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/help.html?content=00001490.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/help.html?content=00000466.html